# Geolocation before for form Submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails form

```
<%= form_for @tree, :html => {:class => "well"} do |f| %>
<p>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :address, :class => 'tree-address' %>
  </div>
</p> 
<p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit :class => "submit", id: "new-tree" %>
  </div>
</p>
```

And here is my JS file, it has my Ajax POST request to send the data to my DB, this works fine, as does the Geocoding function pulled from Google. What i want to do is Geocode the address, then send the Ajax call

```
function createTree(){
  $address = $('.tree-address').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/trees",
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { tree:{
      address:$address, 
    }}
  });
}

function codeAddress() {
  console.log($('address').val());
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results[0].geometry.location)
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.A;
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.F;
    } else {
      console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#new-tree').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     createTree();
   });

  $('#add-tree').on('click', function(){
    console.log("add-tree clicked");
    $('#tree-form').toggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is places autocomplete. See details here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: do you need to get all relevant geodata on select of places in the dropdown ...or something else...please describe ?